# How do I stop my pagination on first and last page?

Tags: jquery

Below I created a jQuery pagination sample. I would like to stop the previous link from working on page one and the next from working on the last page. Currently, the previous will loop to the last page if clicked on the first page and likewise, the next will loop to the first if clicked on the last page. What is the best way to accomplish this?

```js
var page = 1;

function showPage(page) {
    $('.post').hide();
    $('#page'+page).show();
    $('#myPageNum').text(page);
}

function prevPage() {
    if (page == 1) {
        page = $('.pagination .post').length;
    } else {
        page--;
    }
    showPage(page);
}

function nextPage() {
    if (page == $('.pagination .post').length) {
        page = 1;
    } else {
        page++;
    }
    showPage(page);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    showPage(page);
    
    $('#prev').click(prevPage);
    $('#next').click(nextPage);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pagination">
    <div class="post" id="page1">
        <h3> head1 </h3>
        <p> Test1 </p>
    </div>

    <div class="post" id="page2">
        <h3> head2 </h3>
        <p> Test2 </p>
    </div>

    <div class="post" id="page3">
        <h3> head3 </h3>
        <p> Test3 </p>
    </div>

    <div class="post" id="page4">
        <h3> head4 </h3>
        <p> Test4 </p>
    </div>

    <div class="post" id="page5">
        <h3> head5 </h3>
        <p> Test5 </p>
    </div>

    <div class="post" id="page6">
        <h3> head6 </h3>
        <p> Test6 </p>
    </div>
</div>
<a href="#" id="prev">Prev page</a>
<span id="myPageNum">1</span>
<a href="#" id="next">Next page</a>
```

Comment: You should get your pages by ajax requests, and not load them all in the DOM. If you have lots of entries (I mean, thousands), it can take long to load, or even worse: crash the computer. I had to do that myself. It's hard but then it's really more comfortable to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you simply need to amend the logic in your `if` conditions within the `prevPage()` and `nextPage()` functions, so that they only perform an action when the current page is not at the extents of the pages. Try this:

```js
var page = 1;

function showPage(page) {
  $('.post').hide();
  $('#page' + page).show();
  $('#myPageNum').text(page);
}

function prevPage() {
  if (page > 1) {
    page--;
    showPage(page);
  }
}

function nextPage() {
  if (page < $('.pagination .post').length) {
    page++;
    showPage(page);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  showPage(page);

  $('#prev').click(prevPage);
  $('#next').click(nextPage);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pagination">
  <div class="post" id="page1">
    <h3> head1 </h3>
    <p> Test1 </p>
  </div>

  <div class="post" id="page2">
    <h3> head2 </h3>
    <p> Test2 </p>
  </div>

  <div class="post" id="page3">
    <h3> head3 </h3>
    <p> Test3 </p>
  </div>

  <div class="post" id="page4">
    <h3> head4 </h3>
    <p> Test4 </p>
  </div>

  <div class="post" id="page5">
    <h3> head5 </h3>
    <p> Test5 </p>
  </div>

  <div class="post" id="page6">
    <h3> head6 </h3>
    <p> Test6 </p>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="#" id="prev">Prev page</a>
<span id="myPageNum">1</span>
<a href="#" id="next">Next page</a>
```

Comment: I see what you did there. I was close!

Answer (score 2):

Forbid the pagination function from running.
See the `return` statements I added.

```js
var page = 1;

function showPage(page) {
    $('.post').hide();
    $('#page'+page).show();
    $('#myPageNum').text(page);
}

function prevPage() {
    if (page == 1) {
        return;
        page = $('.pagination .post').length;
    } else {
        page--;
    }
    showPage(page);
}

function nextPage() {
    if (page == $('.pagination .post').length) {
      return;
        page = 1;
    } else {
        page++;
    }
    showPage(page);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    showPage(page);
    
    $('#prev').click(prevPage);
    $('#next').click(nextPage);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pagination">
    <div class="post" id="page1">
        <h3> head1 </h3>
        <p> Test1 </p>
    </div>

    <div class="post" id="page2">
        <h3> head2 </h3>
        <p> Test2 </p>
    </div>

    <div class="post" id="page3">
        <h3> head3 </h3>
        <p> Test3 </p>
    </div>

    <div class="post" id="page4">
        <h3> head4 </h3>
        <p> Test4 </p>
    </div>

    <div class="post" id="page5">
        <h3> head5 </h3>
        <p> Test5 </p>
    </div>

    <div class="post" id="page6">
        <h3> head6 </h3>
        <p> Test6 </p>
    </div>
</div>
<a href="#" id="prev">Prev page</a>
<span id="myPageNum">1</span>
<a href="#" id="next">Next page</a>
```